# activate/deactivate config listeners not firing in navigationview to hide navigationbar button in sencha touch 2

Tags: events, event-handling, sencha-touch-2, hidden, navigationcontroller

I am attempting to do something which (at least I believe) should be very straightforward in ST2 but it is not working. I have a main view (`xtype: navigationview`) and a secondary view (`xtype: container`). There is a button in the navigationbar on the main view that should be hidden when navigating to the secondary view and shown when returning to the main view. I have added the code to mark the `setHidden(true)` in the main view config listeners but neither of the events fire.

Is there maybe a better way of doing this?

Main view:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
    xtype: 'main',

    requires: [
        'Ext.dataview.List'
    ],

    config: {
        navigationBar: {
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    iconCls: 'refresh',
                    iconMask: true,
                    itemId: 'refreshBtn',
                    align: 'left'
                }
            ]
        },
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                itemId: 'next-page-button',
                text: 'Next Page'
            }
        ],

        listeners: {
            activate: function() {
                this.query('[itemId=refrehBtn]')[0].setHidden(false);
            },
            deactivate: function() {
                this.query('[itemId=refrehBtn]')[0].setHidden(true);
            }
        }
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.callParent();
    }
});
```

Sencondary view:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main2', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'main2',

    config: {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'panel',
                items: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        html: 'second view'
                    },
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Controller:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.controller.TestController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    config: {
        refs: {
            nextPgBtn: '[itemId=next-page-button]'
        },

        control: {
            nextPgBtn: {
                tap: 'showNextPg'
            }
        }
    },

    showNextPg: function(btn, e, opts) {
        btn.up('navigationview').push({
            xtype: 'main2'
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to change your query to correctly retrieve your button. Change this:

```
this.query('[itemId=refrehBtn]')[0].setHidden(false);
```

to this:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#refreshBtn')[0].setHidden(false);
```

Secondly, instead of using `activate` and `deactivate` event, you should make use of [back](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-event-back)

event which `fires when the back button in the navigation view was tapped.` and [push](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View-event-push) event which `fires when a view is pushed into this navigation view` in order to show and hide your button accordingly:

```
back: function() {
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#refreshBtn')[0].setHidden(false);
},

push: function() {
    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#refreshBtn')[0].setHidden(true);
}
```

Here is a demo: http://www.senchafiddle.com/#GSt6x